# Java - Get List of Wireless Networks in Range

Tags: java, wifi, wireless, ssid, wep

I'm trying to get a list of wireless networks that are in range of the user.  I would like the program to be able to get SSID (if broadcasting), Security Type (WEP, WPA, WPA2), and maybe a couple other pieces of information.  I want to do the whole project through java because of its platform independence, but I will have a mechanism setup to handle OS's since I heard that can be a problem.  I would first like to get it running on Windows.  My problem is, getting the information.
     I have heard of jWlanScan, but I can't seem to find a way to call the methods in my code. I have wlanscan.jar referenced as a library in my project. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "but I can't seem to find a way to call the methods in my code" Can you explain what is exact problem, what IDE or tool you are using?

Comment: I am using the netbeans IDE.  I have wlanscan.jar added to the libraries folder in netbeans.  When I try anything such as: wlanScan network = new wlanScan(); it can't find the class at all even though the class is in the wlanscan.jar.  I was wondering if there was a different way to do this other than wlanscan.jar or if I could find a way to make wlanscan.jar work.

Comment: Is wlanScan a typo? Try to check-out the source from sf.net and look what they are doing.

Comment: can you try two things: 1. Try to run your program from command prompt keeping this jar file in classpath explicitly. 2. Try to unzip the jar file and check what all classes are there, is there a class name wlanScan() ?

Comment: There is a class called wlanScan() and the constructor does not take any parameters. I think I might have figured out my issue though.  The jWlanScan.jar contains all .class files (which if i am remembering correctly means that they are now object files). In order to use the jWlanScan.jar I would have to use Reflection (see: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to use the methods in the class file.  Does that sound right?